# Query on JSON response returns, Parse exception Unexpected end of input

Tags: json, api, request, postman, http-get

Good day,

Hope you are well.

I am trying to use the [Vincere API](https://api.vincere.io/documentation.html#operation/searchJob), and trying to query the response to only return where `private_job:0`. I am using Postman to test the API.

When I use the below request, doing my best to follow the instructions on the [Documentation](https://api.vincere.io/documentation.html#operation/searchJob):

```
https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date asc?q=private_job:0
```

I get the following response:

```
"Parse exception Unexpected end of input, expected term_char, ws0, term or term_end (line 1, pos 14):\nprivate_job:0\n             ^\n"
```

If I remove `?q=private_job:0`, I get a valid response.

I am clearly doing something wrong. Please assist.

Comment: @Miya, thank you, I tried this as well. If I try `https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date%20asc?fq="private_job:0"`, I get the following error `"Parse exception Invalid input '\"', expected query (line 1, pos 1):\n\"private_job:0\"\n^\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in query parameter the key name is q ,

q=private_job:0

but in documentation it says instead of q it should be fq

[https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date asc?fq=private_job:0](https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date%20asc?fq=private_job:0)

Also if you are using special character q=private_job:0 # , then give the value in the query parameter session of postman it will url encode it automatically for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I thought for a moment I was being an idiot (and you are right with correcting this), however if I try `https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date%20asc?fq=private_job:0` I get the same error, `"Parse exception Unexpected end of input, expected term_char, ws0, term or term_end (line 1, pos 14):\nprivate_job:0\n             ^\n"`

Comment: `https://domain.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=published_date asc?fq=private_job:0 %23`

Comment: can you try this url froom https till %23 with the space and %23 included

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me as well, turns out my issue was twofold.

Firstly, this error refers to their URL parser expecting to see the end character `%23`, so your query string needs to end with that.

Secondly, I was attempting to query the `job_type` and using the actual string value ie. `job_type:PERMANENT%23`. This actually needs to be the enum value (1 in this case).